# Can't find kernel dump in /var/crash except when I simulate a kernel panic

Tags: kernel

I wish to find out how I can capture a kernel dump file when the VM running on Ubuntu 16.04 crashed/hanged. Below is what I have done so far.

1. I installed `linux-crashdump` on the VM
2. I edited `/etc/default/kdump-tools` to include the line

   ```
   USE_KDUMP=1
   ```

   [image: screenshot of file in text editor]
3. The VM had been crashing/hanging frequently but I failed to obtain any dump file from `/var/crash` folder after I had to restart the VM through vCenter to access the VM's folder via putty.
4. The only time I can successfully retrieve a kernel dump file is when I simulate a kernel panic.